# How to handle SQL Exception for Logon failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a windows form that presents a combo box for the user to select a geographical region and then sets SQL Connections based on the selection and executes a SQL Command.  There is always a good chance the user doesn't have access to the SQL Server.  I set up a try/catch and display the error message to the user but don't really want to break and I'm new to VS C# and am asking for guidance on how to pass control to a point the user can adjust by making a different selection.

Would it be reasonable to pass execution back to the form load?  If yes, how do I do that?  If no, how should it be handled?

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            List<String> distinctTableList = AttributeMap.DistinctTablesList(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            lbTableNames.DataSource = distinctTableList;
        }
    }

    public static List<String> DistinctTablesList(String environment)
    {
        List<String> tables = new List<string>();
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("cbSettings");
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(appSettingSection.Settings[environment].Value);
        using (sqlcon)
        {
                        StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
                        using (sqlcon)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                sqlcon.Open();
                            }
                            catch (SqlException ex)
                            {
                              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }


public partial class frmClassBuilder : Form
{
    private List<AttributeMap> attributeMapList;
    private CacheClassFactory cacheFactory;

    public frmClassBuilder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> environmentList = AttributeMap.EnvironmentList();
        comboBox1.DataSource = environmentList;
    }
 =============================================================
    using (sqlcon)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you instantiate the `sqlcon` with the connection string? What do you mean "I dont really want to break"? You could get creative here, if there aren't too many regions, you could possibly try all the values in the environment list and remove entries that cause an exception only leaving items in the combobox that are valid environments/connectionstrings for the user to select - that way it wont break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following approach in one of enterprise desktop clients and it is still used.

Assuming you have combobox_SelectedIndexChanged() method, it should look like this:

```
    public void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged()
    {
        string selectedCountry = "country"; //build actual connection string as you do now.
        string connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=Detrack;Integrated Security=True;", selectedCountry);
        var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (sqlCon)
        {
            // Disable some controls
            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                // Disable "OK"/"Next" button
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                ///Enable controls
            }

            sqlCon.Close();

            // "OK"/"Next" button
        }
    }
```

In this method, you check if connection can be opened,
If it can't:

- display error message
- disable controls that allow user to continue interaction, until correct selection is made

If it can, just close connection and go forth to the next part of the code, where you actually use the connection.

You'll also require some sort of "Checking connection" message displayed to the user and blocking his interaction while connection is being checked.

Comment: It looks like simply placing a return after MessageBox takes me back to the ComboBox and that appears to work well.

I followed execution in debug and noticed the Finally statement executes regardless.  I'm surely to inexperienced to realize the usefulness of this in some other case but don't see the need here.

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: In this particular case, finally block allows to enable controls (i.e. country combobox) unregarding connection check result. You can write "Enable controls" block twice in catch block and after connection close part, but "finally" allows to write it only once, as its always executed.